# Конструктор копирования. Как правильно создать копию

Tags: c++, указатели, конструктор-копирования

У меня есть некоторый класс item, который имеет указатель в своём теле.

```
class item{
protected:
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int price;
    std::string description;
    QPixmap* pic=nullptr;
    string picpath;
```

Нужно ли мне делать свой конструктор копирования в этом случае и как он должен выглядеть? Как первый вариант или второй?
1 Вариант:

```
item::item(const item& x):id(x.id),name(x.name),price(x.price),description(x.description),pic(x.pic),picpath(x.picpath)
{
}
```

Второй:

```
item::item(const item& x):id(x.id),name(x.name),price(x.price),description(x.description),picpath(x.picpath)
{
    pic=new QPixmap(*x.pic);
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл делать `pic` указателем? Если сделать его просто `QPixmap pic;`, то самописный конструктор копирования не потребуется.

Comment: Если чесно, я сам не знаю, в С++ вообще не понятно, как правильно что делать, когда работают оба варианта, то вообще не ясно((

Comment: первый вариант равносилен конструктору копирования по умолчанию.... какой использовать — зависит от того, что тебе нужно.... ЗЫ: третий вариант — использовать `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @Fat-Zer  мне просто нужен правильный конструктор копирования. Чтоб использовать shared ptr мне нужно переписать пол программы((

Comment: @andybelous2, они оба «правильные», просто разные... какой использовать — зависит в частности от того, кто отвечает за время жизни `pic`; если `item` сам, то вероятней всего нужен второй вариант и лучше использовать `std::unique_ptr` или `std::shared_ptr`; если какая-то внешняя сущность, то вероятней всего нужен первый вариант.

Comment: да, кстати учитывая специфику Qt, **в данном случае** у варианта, когда `item` сам отвечает за удаление накладных расходов быть не должно...

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен. Никто кроме вас не знает и не может знать ответа на вопрос о том, нужен ли вам конструктор копирования и какой. Является ли указатель `pic` владельцем своего ресурса, или просто ссылается на него? От этого и зависит ответ на вопрос. Знаете это только вы.